# Android emulator generates error messages

Tags: android-emulator

Starting emulator with RUN Android, it seems to start correctly at the beginning, but at the end appears following error message:

[2011-06-30 15:03:34 - Test] Installing Test.apk...
[2011-06-30 15:04:19 - Test] Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
[2011-06-30 15:04:19 - Test] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2011-06-30 15:04:19 - Test] Launch canceled!

I installed all 4-times. I modified the virtual device many times, I made some new ones. But still the same. I have a new laptop with Win7.

Comment: something in your android manifest file is wrong, check your logcat output. You can add the logcat view in eclipse: Window - Show View - Other - Android - LogCat

Answer (score 2):

I guess that your application is installing fine but you don't have your default activity set in your **androidmanifest.xml**. Please take a look at it and make sure the package name and the activity name match with that of your project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="Your Package Name!!"

  ...blah.. blah...!

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="Your java file name... eg: .Pedro for Pedro.java"
              android:label="@string/app_name">

       ....blah... blah...!

    </activity>

</application> 
</manifest>
```